# Error when testing using jest-styled-components' toHaveStyleRule with enzyme

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I use a styled component within a component that I am testing, it looks like this:

```
export const StyledCheckboxGroup = styled(CheckboxGroup)`
> .ant-checkbox-group-item {
display: ${props => (props.inline ? 'inline-block' : 'block')};
}
`
```

I have a test that looks like this:

```
it('renders an inline widget with the appropriate style rules', () => {
  const options = {
    enumOptions: [
      {
        value: 'one',
        label: 'One'
      },
      {
        label: 'Two',
        value: 'two'
      }
    ],
    inline: true
  }

  const wrapper = mount(<Checkboxes options={options} />)
  const item = wrapper.find(StyledCheckboxGroup)
  const subject = item.find('.ant-checkbox-group-item')
  expect(subject).toHaveStyleRule('display', 'inline-block')
})
```

I would expect to be able to match my styling rule using enzyme's mount. I have two results for the `subject` and the output of the assertion looks this:

```
"Expected [object Object] to be a component from react-test-renderer, or a mounted enzyme component."

"But had an error, TypeError: Cannot read property '_renderedComponent' of undefined"
```

Digging into the source I found that:

```
const renderedComponent = received.node._reactInternalInstance._renderedComponent
```

is where the error is, it can find the `_reactInternalInstance` on the component but not the `_renderedComponent`.

Comment: Could you run a snapshot test `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()`, to test how the rendered result looks like. It may also help to use a string in the `find` method: `wrapper.find('StyledCheckboxGroup')`

Comment: The `toHaveStyleRule` function has been completely rewritten recently. Please upgrade the library and let me know if it works. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @MicheleBertoli I updated to `4.0.1`, I have a new problem, it removes all static classNames when I use `toMatchSnapshot` method. Take a look [here](https://hastebin.com/jiqohuvage.coffeescript)

Comment: @MicheleBertoli `toHaveStyleRule` works correctly now, though.

Comment: @vamsiampolu Please upgrade to 4.1.0 which fixes all the problems related to custom class names.
Also, I'm happy to hear that toHaveStyleRule works 